# Protecting a separating wall from concrete floor and CMU blocks

Tags: framing, waterproofing

I am rebuilding a (non-structural) separating wall. The wall will be attached to the (old) concrete floor and CMU block walls.

Previous users have suggested using sill wrap between the boards and the walls/floor. I am finding it flimsy and hard to keep in place.

**Would I be a total idiot to use a vapor barrier instead?** I imagine taping a 1' wide path of vapor barrier securely to the walls and floor. Then I would stick build the frame, using a powder actuated nail gun to secure the boards to the walls and the floor.

When finished, I would either cut the vapor barrier maybe 1" from the frame, pull the edges up and staple them to the frame.

[image]

Comment: I'm not understanding why the sill gasket is hard to keep in place.  Simply wrap some tape around the gasket and the framing member.  Once you anchor the members to floor or wall, there should be no problem keeping it in place.

Comment: @Huesmann I guess I'm being foolish here - I felt like I would need to remove the tape after the board is fastened to the floor/walls. Sounds like I could just leave the tape.

Comment: No need to remove any tape.  The sill gasket provides a moisture-proof barrier between concrete and wood (as well as physical distance), and so does pretty much any tape you'd be likely to use.

Comment: @Huesmann Sometimes I wonder how I manage to walk and breathe at the time same. If you need me, I'll be over here in the corner with my dunce hat. :) But seriously, thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious - I was treating the sill wrap as if it were some magical barrier not to be altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for using a PT board or sill  where the bottom framing member would touch concrete is to prevent wicking, or as a barrier against moisture.

If the concrete floor you are building on has an impervious moisture barrier underneath, that is not even necessary.  However in many instances the bottom or sill plate is still PT or does have a barrier. Beyond code is not a bad thing in this instance.

As for against the walls the idea is that moisture will not come through so a barrier is not needed.  However this could be untrue if you were building a new wall in a basement.  In that case you would be best served to seal the block wall from moisture before attaching any wall to it.

The idea that it is simply bad to attach any white wood framing against any concrete surface is wrong.  The issue is moisture, and preventing any wicking or absorbing of moisture into the wood that could cause rot.

In your case, using sill wrap or tar paper under the bottom plate makes sense. adding any barrier to the studs against the wall would depend on what is on the other side of the wall.  If it is just an exterior wall nothing is needed. If it is in a basement the wall should be waterproofed or sealed prior to attaching anything to it.  Then if you feel another barrier is needed stapling tar paper strips, or even duct tape would qualify to prevent wicking. I have seen some framers add tar paper strips to just the first 12" or so of the studs   where the concrete was suspected to not have a vapor barrier underneath.

Your idea with the plastic is ambitious. The tar paper or tape would be easier.  Another alternative is solid foil backed insulation panels against the block, ( polyisocyanurate). then the framing. There is you barrier and some extra insulation as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure my basement does not have a vapor barrier underneath - the previous separating wall rotted - the wood was clearly wicking moisture from the wall and floors (there were visibly wet strips where the wood was attached previously). I really like the idea of attaching something to the frame itself to prevent wicking.

Comment: FWIW the basement walls are below grade and I know I've got a minor water problem to solve - so I do feel the need to put something between the studs and the CMU walls. Is there a class of product I can search for, which I could directly attach to the bottom plate? If I can find something like that, I think I could get away with building the frame on the ground and then raising it up instead of stick building.

Comment: I know of nothing made expressly for attaching to the bottom plate.  Others here may know.  I myself have used 30# tar paper. stapled to the bottom plate.

Comment: @negacao are you planning to solve the water problem before you put up your wall?

Comment: @Huesmann I have done what I can for now - two thick coats of drylok along the affected area. The area where the wall is isn't too bad, and there's no standing water anywhere. Other sections of the wall have much bigger issues. Either way, it won't be totally solved until I can get a proper French drain installed at the footer, along with sealing the exterior.

Comment: I'm not certain that a plastic barrier under the floor completely alleviates the need for a sill sealer and/or PT bottom plate. On the slab I just had poured, the footing doesn't have any plastic barrier while the slab does. Moisture won't come directly into the slab from below, but could easily wick in from the footing. Since the wall sits on the footing, I used both sill sealer _and_ a PT bottom plate. Otherwise, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Chalk line where the wall goes, put a bead of caulk on the concrete, put the sill foam down on the chalk line, put a bead of caulk on top of foam, put bottom plate on.

I like the brand big stretch for this.